# Why I cannot install my composer new package?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

The package - https://packagist.org/packages/drakonli/php-utils

My composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "drakonli/php-utils": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

The error I get when i use "composer install"

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package drakonli/php-utils could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have added a tag to this package, so it should not be the problem with stability of version.

What I also tried - I tried to search for my package on packagist AND using command composer search. And this is what I got:

When I try to search for **"drakonli/"** - I CAN find my package, but when I try to search for **"drakonli/php-utils"** or **"php-utils"** I CAN'T find my package.

Help, pls.

> UPDATE

I was wrong - the package is found but it's on the 1608 page after packages that don't even have "php" or anything in it's name. Even when using the package full name.

> UPDATE #2

```
composer search drakonli
```

result:

```
drakonli/php-utils PHP lib of different utility interfaces/classes
```

AND

```
composer info drakonli/php-utils
```

result:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Package drakonli/php-utils not found
```

Losing my mind here :D

Answer (score 0):

After about 12 hours it fixed on it's own...